# Does Rails initializers gets called when I run rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer

I want to put my chargify conf inside the initializer,
but I found the initializer won't execute in my rails c, is there a way to invoke my initializers so I can test in my console?

```
    Chargify.configure do |c|
      c.api_key   = "keykey"
      c.subdomain = "test-site"
    end
```

Comment: every file in `initializers` directory shall be auto-executed by Rails. Which also have effect in console

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, every `.rb` file in `config/initializers` is run whenever you run the console, run a rake task, or run your tests. Additonally, the environment configuration (`config/environments`) is run  before the initializers.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent this behavior, so to only run initialization code upon starting the server, but not on starting the console etc.?

Comment: @Reinier use an environment variable.

Comment: It's possible to use a reference to the `Rails::Server` object with `if defined?(::Rails::Server)` in one of your initializers.

Answer (score 22):

The `config/initializers` will execute, but only once, on initial load.  So if you're making changes to `config/initializers` while the console is running you won't see the results of those changes happening.

Your best option is to stop and restart `rails c`, or you can type the `reload!` command in the console.

Also, if you are using spring that will sometimes prevent changed initializers from reloading.  in that case do `spring stop` before you restart the console.

Comment: The reason I was dubious is that when I want to log staff in initializers files using "p 'loaded?' ", it's doesn't always show up, even when I exited and then open my Rails console.

Comment: oh wow.. I didn't know exiting out of the rails console didn't stop spring. Wasted so many hours because of this :(  Thank you so much for this answer!

Answer (score 5):

Apparently not anymore unless you disable spring:

> export DISABLE_SPRING=1

Comment: or run the one-liner `DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails console`